# JSON - Multi dimensional object

Tags: javascript, xml, json

I want to create a json object on javascript. I want to access using index to add new data. I read some commands that json doesn't allow adding new data using index. How can I do it?

I want to do this : `datas.days[index].add = hour;`

```
<datas>
        <days>
            <day_id="0">
                <hour="00:00">
                    <val>10</val>
                </hour>
                <hour="01:00">
                    <val>15</val>
                    <val>8</val>
                    <val>10</val>
                </hour>
                ......
            </day_id>

            <day_id="1">
                <hour="00:00">
                    <val>7</val>
                    <val>9</val>
                </hour>
                <hour="01:00">
                    <val>8</val>
                    <val>10</val>
                    <val>6</val>
                    <val>11</val>
                </hour>
                ......
            </day_id>
            .......
        </days>
    </datas>
```

Comment: It seems you rather want to parse the XML into an object, not create JSON. JSON is a textual data representation just like XML. It can't really be "accessed" until it's parsed into a data structure of whichever language you are using.

Comment: no, I want to create this. I add this example to understand easily.

Comment: Your example is in xml, not json

Comment: Now it's even less clear what you have and want. Maybe you just have to learn how objects and arrays work in JS? Check out the MDN tutorial about [**objects**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects) and [**arrays**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Predefined_Core_Objects#Array_Object). If you really want to create JSON, have a look at [**`JSON.stringify`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify).

Comment: my data is 3 dimensional, size is 7*288*n. If I use array, is it a bad solution? (n is not constant)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `[]` to create an array which can be accessed by index, like this:

```
{[
   1,
   4,
   1,
   7
]}
```

Comment: What are those `{...}` supposed to be?